# Constructor class cannot be applied

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

Could someone please explain to me what is wrong with my constructor method? I have tried a million different things but nothing seems to work. I am supposed to create a class (`ScanArray`) that contains a constructor and two methods that find the max and min values of an array created in the main class. Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign7_Polk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] midTerm1 = new int[8];
        int[] midTerm2 = new int[8];
        int[] finalExam = new int[8];
        int[] grades = new int[8];

        for (int i = 0; i < midTerm1.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the 8 Mid Term 1 grades: ");
            midTerm1[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < midTerm2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the 8 Mid Term 2 grades: ");
            midTerm2[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < finalExam.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter 8 Final Exam grades: ");
            finalExam[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            grades[i] = (midTerm1[i] + midTerm2[i] + finalExam[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class ScanArray {

    int Max = 0;

    public ScanArray(int grades) {}

    int FindMax(int[] grades) {
        int Max = grades[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < grades.length; i++) {
            if (grades[i] > Max) {
                Max = grades[i];
            }
        }
        return Max;
    }

    int FindMin(int[] grades) {
        int Min = grades[0];
        for (int i = 1; i > grades.length; i++) {
            if (grades[i] < Min) {
                Min = grades[i];
            }
        }
        return Min;

        ScanArray findarray = new ScanArray();

        int highest = findarray.FindMax();
        int lowest = findarray.FindMin();

        System.out.println("The highest grade is " + highest);
        System.out.println("The lowest grade is " + lowest);
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you setting the grades that you pass to your ScanArray(int grades) if you are not using that constructor why have you used it and how will you create the ScanArray object. do you have info on how constructors work in java

Answer (score 0):

Add default constructor to your class

```
public ScanArray(){


}
```

Since you have defined a constructor for `ScanArray` class with parameters, Compiler will not auto-generate default no-args constructor. Please add it manually

Other way is just change the way you construct the `ScanArray` instance like new `ScanArray(5);`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the argument from the constructor, just have

```
public ScanArray(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your constructor `public ScanArray(int grades)` - it does nothing, the compiler will add the default parameter-less constructor for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ScanArray()
{
}
```

use above or remove the constructor

```
int highest = findarray.FindMax();//pass integer array
int lowest = findarray.FindMin();//pass integer array
```

check this out still you need to pass integer array to get highest and lowest value.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a constructor other than the default `no-argument constructor`, Java doesn't add the default constructor automatically to your class. So in this case because you defined the constuctor with arguments:

```
public ScanArray(int grades)
{
}
```

You must add explicitly the `no-argument constructor` if you are ever going to use it in your code:

```
public ScanArray()
{
}
```